# Method which takes in record ids and stores them?

Tags: apex

I am trying to make a method in a helper class such that it fetches the record ids and stores them.

Others should be able to call this method whenever they require the record type ID instead of coding it.

Comment: Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Development').getRecordTypeId();

....this is what i dont understand, with this line what ids wil i get, i can get each record ids of one sobject i state in it?so i have to use this line multiple times for each object ?

Comment: also i did see those two questions marked already answered, i am sorry i didn't understand it, if you know any links that will make my understanding a little better about these topics that will be nice,also the answer to above doubt.Thanks again

Comment: ........anyone?